# How to terminate a suspended jsp thread(suspended by calling a function which contains a loop check)?

Tags: java, multithreading, jsp, blocking

I have a jsp page contains code to call a function to start a server socket, which will block the rest of the jsp code since I put the serversocket.accept() in an indefinitely loop to serve any incoming client socket connection request. My question is How to exit that jsp page thread after it stared the server socket. I doubt the suspended jsp thread may lead to the memory leak of tomcat. Below is the jsp code:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ page import="com.jeepinjava.pttwebserver.bean.*" %>
<% 
TcpServerSocket.startListening();
System.out.println("started");
%>
```

TcpServerSocket.startListening() suspends the current jsp thread. Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: I don't think there is a way.  Basically, it is a really bad idea to do that.  From a number of respects.

Comment: Do you think the code should be put in a servlet instead?

Comment: That would be a start.  However, anything that starts a background activity from a web page needs great care.  It can potentially be exploited as a denial of service attack.  A "leakage" may require a (full) app server restart to fix it.  And so on.

Comment: Yes, I should avoid this approach and try to do those stuff on tomcat startup through a listener servlet. Thanks for your suggestion:)